# How do I set sysctl key in kubernetes pod on a minikube node?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm using k8s v 1.7. Following the guide in [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/sysctl-cluster/), my deployment has the following in its spec:

```
annotations:
  security.alpha.kubernetes.io/unsafe-sysctls: net.core.somaxconn=16384
```

But when applying that using `kubectl`, I get the following error:

```
forbidden sysctl: "net.core.somaxconn" not whitelisted
```

Now the docs say I should run something like this in the node:

```
kubelet --experimental-allowed-unsafe-sysctls 'net.core.somaxconn'
```

But I don't know where to run that command. I tried inside `minikube ssh` but `kubelet` doesn't seem to be installed.

I'm looking for something like:

```
minikube start --extra-config='allow net.core.somaxconn'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with this and it seemed to work

```
minikube start --extra-config=kubelet.AllowedUnsafeSysctls=net.core.somaxconn
```

Extracted from here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cmd/kubelet/app/options/options.go

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.